# Displaying PageNotFound component in every page. React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, routes, react-router

I don't understand why my PageNotFound component is displayed all over my app even though I've put it at the bottom of all of my routes? The problem is maybe the nested routes but I still don't know what to do. I would appreciate the help, here is my code:

```
    <>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <>
      <div className="content-wrap">
        <div className="main-content">
          <Menu />
          <main className="main-pages">
            <Switch>
              <Container>
                {/* admin */}
                {userInfo && userInfo.isAdmin && (
                  <>
                    <PrivateRoute
                      path="/admin/userlist"
                      component={UserList}
                      exact
                    />
                    <PrivateRoute
                      path="/admin/userlist/:pageNumber"
                      component={UserList}
                      exact
                    />
                    <PrivateRoute
                      path="/admin/user/:id/edit"
                      component={UserEdit}
                      exact
                    />
                    <PrivateRoute
                      path="/admin/createuser"
                      component={UserCreate}
                    />
                    <PrivateRoute
                      path="/admin/user/:id/contact"
                      component={UserContact}
                      exact
                    />
                    <PrivateRoute
                      path="/admin/productlist"
                      component={ProductList}
                      exact
                    />
                    <PrivateRoute
                      path="/admin/productlist/:pageNumber"
                      component={ProductList}
                      exact
                    />
                    <PrivateRoute
                      path="/admin/product/:id/edit"
                      component={ProductEdit}
                      exact
                    />
                    <PrivateRoute
                      path="/admin/orderlist"
                      component={OrderList}
                      exact
                    />
                    <PrivateRoute
                      path="/admin/orderlist/:pageNumber"
                      component={OrderList}
                      exact
                    />
                  </>
                )}

                {/* private */}
                <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/shipping" component={Shipping} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/payment" component={Payment} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/placeorder" component={PlaceOrder} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/order/:id" component={Order} />

                {/* public */}
                <Route path="/products/:id" component={ProductDetail} />
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route path="/cart/:id?" component={Cart} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                <Route exact path="/search/:word" component={Home} />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/search/:word/page/:pageNumber"
                  component={Home}
                />
                <Route exact path="/page/:pageNumber" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route component={PageNotFound}/> 
              </Container>
            </Switch>
          </main>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

I've tried changing the orders and so on but still no use..

Answer (score 0):

Try out:
`<Route path="*" component={PageNotFound}/>`

Comment: Ive tried, Did not work :/

Comment: Try getting that <Container/> out of the Switch, so that the Switch component only has route components.

Comment: Did not work either thx anyways :)